# How to optimize call rate for leaky bucket throttling?

Tags: python

I am connecting to a web service via their API with Python.  They have leaky bucket throttling in place with a max burst of 40 calls with a restore rate of 2 calls/second.  I know I can just make a request every 0.5 seconds and never hit the limit but if I need to make a thousand calls, won't I lose time in the latency time of the actual call. Which will add up to a significant amount of time after enough calls.

So, if I wanted to lose the least amount to time possible over the thousands of calls I need to make, could I do something like this:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

time1 = datetime.now()
count = 0
for url in api_urls:
    api_resp = requests.get(url)
    count += 1

    if count == 40:
        time2 = datetime.now()
        time.sleep(20-(time2-time1)) # 20s total time to restore 40 calls
        count = 0                    #   minus the time it took to
        time1 = datetime.now()       #   get to 40 total calls
```

Is the  restore rate applying during the time it takes to get to 40 calls?  If so, wouldn't I NOT have to wait a full 20 seconds to do another burst of 40 because it actually took some time to make the first 40 calls?

Is the time it takes to burst 40 calls so insignificant that it really doesn't matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *won't I lose time in the latency time of the actual call. Which will add up to a significant amount of time after enough calls* - I don't know - **do you**?

Comment: Yes, I guess I could run a test to make a burst of 40 calls and get the total time. But, even if it is negligible, would my code be correct for accounting for that time?